# Mobile application dev or web dev

Tags: java, flutter, frontend, mobile-application, web-frontend

I am learning programming, I learned Java, I took a little experience with Android, I made a simple application, then I started to learn flutter, I took a course and i created a simple application, and now many people tell me and I see that the web is more widespread and has more job opportunities, and I want to be a Frontend developer  What would you advise me to continue learning flutter or go to the web because I want to work as a freelancer or in a company?

Comment: creating simple app does not mean you know everything. You can deep dive in to the frameworks. Also you can create web apps with flutter as well.

Comment: I didn't mean I learned everything.

Comment: @Sunny I didn't mean I learned everything and people say flutter web is newly born and it has many issues

Comment: @Sunny so do advise me to stick with flutter or not!

Comment: from what I know because I've lot of experience in flutter as well. I would advice you to go with flutter.

Comment: @Sunny thank you so much I appreciate that 

Answer (score 1):

I think everyone would agree that only you yourself can decide what to do with your own life. We have neither right to decide it for you nor will to bear such responsibility.

"I want to fly planes, but I also want to drive a bus or maybe I should be a train operator?" All those professions have the "driver/pilot" role in common, yet they are very different. Just because everything you mentioned involves programming, doesn't mean it is all the same and learning a few lines of code here and there doesn't make a pro, but I'm sure you know that.

If you want a decent job, I suggest you to explore your local job market, see what real companies need most. Then think about the future - will they still need it by the time you finish studying it?

Keep in mind that the tech landscape in always changing. Flutter can be hot now, but in few years - who knows? For example, nobody in their sane mind today really considers Xamarin and C# as something to learn for cross-platform mobile dev, but it had future.. at some point. Anyway, hope you get the idea.

Comment: I asked one of my friends about local jobs cuz he work in a company and he said web is more needed

Answer (score 0):

personally, I advise you to expose yourself to as many technologies as you can to increase your chances of obtaining a job and also because there is no way of knowing for sure which technologies your future employer will require from you and hence I say go ahead and learn web development since it's one of the most wanted skillsets in software development.

as for freelancing it really depends on what type of freelancing jobs you want or will accept.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are right, it is easier to find a job in web development than in mobile app development, my suggestion is that you continue on web development, your aim should not be to become a front-end developer only but rather try to become a fullstack web developer.

Comment: Thanks you I appreciate that❤️

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to quickly get a job, I would stick with Android and maybe learn iOS as well. There are plenty of jobs in mobile, even as a junior developer. I would not invest too heavily in Flutter, it has all but lost the hybrid mobile framework user space, at least from a jobs perspective. Pick up React Native if you must. Learning web from scratch will be difficult; there are lots of nuances and different technology stacks, and companies are often looking for a wide variety of experience.

Comment: It depends entirely on your goals. If your goal is to quickly achieve a job, Flutter is not as popular of a hybrid framework and your options will be limited.

Comment: It's a perfectly good framework, there are just not many job opportunities available for it. If you're freelancing a custom app from scratch (in charge of designing the entire app) you can use Flutter. However it is less likely that existing apps are written in Flutter, than say Ionic or React Native.

Comment: you are right I think because it is newly born and react native is popular and growing fast

Comment: Another benefit with React Native is that it is based in JavaScript, and uses React, which means that the skills translate pretty well to web development.